# Combine states in multistate analysis using mstate

Tags: r

I am performing a multistate analysis in R using mstate. My dataset looks like this:

```
   subject start_status start_time aki_1_status aki_1_time rec_1_status rec_1_time aki_2_status aki_2_time rec_2_status rec_2_time aki_3_status aki_3_time
1 IDISA0001            1          0            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
2 IDISA0002            1          0            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
3 IDISA0004            1          0            1        6.1            0       11.3            0       11.3            0       11.3            0       11.3
4 IDISA0005            1          0            1        2.1            1       10.2            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
5 IDISA0006            1          0            1        3.1            1       11.2            1       31.1            1       47.2            0       90.3
6 IDISA0008            1          0            1        1.1            0        2.3            0        2.3            0        2.3            0        2.3
  rec_3_status rec_3_time aki_4_status aki_4_time rec_4_status rec_4_time death_status death_time
1            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
2            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
3            0       11.3            0       11.3            0       11.3            1       11.3
4            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
5            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3            0       90.3
6            0        2.3            0        2.3            0        2.3            1        2.3
```

I wrote the following code, which works fine:

```
#create transition matrix
tmat <- transMat(x = list(c(2, 10), c(3, 10), c(4, 10), c(5, 10), c(6, 10), c(7, 10), c(8, 10), c(9, 10), c(10), c()),
                            names = c("start", "aki_1", "rec_1", "aki_2", "rec_2", "aki_3", "rec_3", "aki_4", "rec_4", "death"))
tmat

dlong <- msprep(time = c(NA, "aki_1_time", "rec_1_time", "aki_2_time", "rec_2_time", "aki_3_time", "rec_3_time", 
                         "aki_4_time", "rec_4_time", "death_time"),
                status = c(NA, "aki_1_status", "rec_1_status", "aki_2_status", "rec_2_status", "aki_3_status", "rec_3_status", 
                           "aki_4_status", "rec_4_status", "death_status"),
                data = d, id = "subject", trans = tmat)

#estimate all transitions at the same time
class(dlong$subject)
dlong$subject[dlong$Tstart > dlong$Tstop]
sfall <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status) ~ strata(trans), data=dlong)
msfall <- msfit(sfall, trans=tmat)
plot(msfall, use.ggplot = TRUE)
```

Now I want to make a simpler model in which:

I combine aki_1_status, aki_2_status, aki_3_status and aki_4_status in one state called aki.

I combine rec_1_status, rec_2_status, rec_3_status and rec_4_status in one state called rec.

All subjects start in start_status, from which they can move to either aki or death.
From aki, subjects can move to either rec or death.
From rec, subjects can move to either aki or death.
Death is an absorbing state.

How can I restructure my date to perform this analysis?